# fopen() not working or showing errors

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite

I want to create a new file along with the the creation of a record in my db. The db part works fine, but the file part isn't working. I want to create a file in another folder in the root directory and I used the same code with changes in the file name. Despite setting `ini_set('display_errors',3)` the code doesn't return any errors, I've also tried `fopen($file_name,"w") or die("unable to open file")`, still the code ran. I've given IIS_IUSRS full control over the directory. Here is my code

```
$data = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,"Select * from content where link='$url'")); //fetch data from db
$id = $data['id'];
$file_name="/files/$id.html"; //sets file name
$file = fopen($file_name,"w"); //creates the file
fwrite($file,$_POST['desc']); //writes to the file
fclose($file); //closes the file
```

Comment: Is this in windows?

Comment: What is the result of `is_writable($file_name)` http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php also a good idea in general to add braces around the variable `$file_name="/files/{$id}.html";`

Comment: this is in windows, `is_writable($file_name)` doesn't return anything. I've tried opening an existing file in the same directory, and it returns  failed to open stream: No such file or directory. The problem is php won't go to root directory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was PHP wasn't going to the root directory. I added `$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and replaced `$file_name="/files/$id.html"` with `$file_name="$root/files/$id.html";` and it worked like a charm.